# 2016 Terminal Server - RDS Host wrong, how to fix

Tags: rds, windows-terminal-services

Probably not a great title, but when I run Get-RDServer I get a name:  xxxxx-TERM**NEW**.xxxx.com

The name of the server is: xxxxx-TERM**INAL**.xxxx.com

I was getting redirection errors, but then added a record in my hosts file to point the local IP to the xxxxx-TERM**NEW**.xxxx.com name.  When I look at RDS Overview (Server Manager), I see the name TERMNEW in the deployment servers.

Under RDS > Servers, I see the TERMINAL server name.  Under services it shows every service on the TERMINAL server name.

Under RDS > Collections I see TERMNEW in Host Servers and TERMINAL in Connections

I really want this working as it should be.  Users have no problem connecting to the server, but I don't like things configured wrong.  Additionally, some users when logging in can't access things like the Windows Start Menu or Windows Explorer (Explorer shows "no such interface supported")

It's really a mess whoever got this server up and running.  I'm guessing TERMNEW was the original name, they installed RDS, configured RDS, then changed the name and things got a bit wonky (huge guessing game here).

Comment: I'd recommend installing a new session host from scratch, add it to the collection, and remove the old one from the collection before deleting the server itself.

Comment: I've tried that, but when I add a session host via the Server Admin at:  RDS > Overview >Deployment Servers > Tasks >Add RD Session Host Servers: 

I get the error:  "Failed: Exception of Type: 'Microsoft.RemoteDesktopServices.Common.RDManagementException' was thrown